# AWS Amplify Setting up Admin UI takes very long

Tags: amazon-web-services, mobile, aws-amplify

I want to enable the Admin UI for my Amplify project.
But there's always just a Screen "Setting up Admin UI...".
[That's the message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PGHo.png)

I've tried it at different times, on different devices and different Browsers. (I know, the last two points don't make much sense with a Cloud Service)

I'm using "aws Educate" and there it says "CloudFront service is temporarily unavailable". Could this be the reason?
How long did the process take in your cases?

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

About 40 seconds. What have you tried to troubleshoot?  If you setup CloudTrail you should see "CreateBackendConfig" (and corresponding "RemoveBackendConfig" if switching off) call from Amplify. Any error codes?